# Main window and QTable

Tags: c++, qt

1. What is the command to open the main window of my program at the center of the screen? Or rather, in what documentation section I can find it?
2. Is there a command to set the same width of columns in a QTable? I tried with horizontalHeaderDefaultSectionSize but QTCreator says QTable don't have this argument
3. As I select QTable column, the header text becomes bold: can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. By default, window manager decides the initial position of main window, and usually it is the center of the screen (at least on Windows). If you want some custom position, call `QWidget::move`.
2. `setDefaultSectionSize` is a `QHeaderView` function, so you need to call it as `table->horizontalHeader ()->setDefaultSectionSize ()`.
3. You should probably use `table->horizontalHeader ()->setHighlightSections (false)` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

1) Well this could be find by google: ([link](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/21285))

```
QMainWindow w;
int width = w.frameGeometry().width();
int height = w.frameGeometry().height();

QDesktopWidget wid;

int screenWidth = wid.screen()->width();
int screenHeight = wid.screen()->height();

w.setGeometry((screenWidth/2)-(width/2),(screenHeight/2)-(height/2),width,height);

w.show();
```

2) Well if you want to use `defaultSectionSize` for your `QTableView`, you should call it from it's horizontal header instance, which can be accessed by `tableView->horizontalHeader ()->setDefaultSectionSize (x)`.

Though if you want to set them default not initially sometime in the future, maybe iterating all of them using `tableView->model ()->columnCount ()` and calling `setColumnWidth` on each will do.

3) Well as it mentioned in [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#highlightSections-prop) `setHighlightSections` of class `QHeaderView` is responsible for that, so you have to call `tableView->horizontalHeader ()->setHighlightSections (false)` if you do not want them to get bold.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to read more about Qt Model/View, I hope [this source](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/modelview.html) help you. It is some examples.